# Bitmap class for videoview

Tags: android

We use bitmap class for imageview_and I want know what the class for videoview instead bitmap?

Comment: Try to make better your question, show what you tried to do in code.. if not i think this question would be closed

Comment: I want created on activity instead of many activity for my Listview'item

Comment: In other hand we use a bitmap class for imageview_what the class for video view instead of bitmap

Answer (score 1):

**Example of VideoView **

> MainActivity.java

```
  private VideoView videoView;
         private Button videoPlay;

           @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);        

    videoPlay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    videoPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

            }
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
if(v==videoPlay){
videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/blonde_secretary.3gp");
                videoView.start(); 
}
}
```

> main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.videotest.MainActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoview"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoview"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]